# wap Letter "X" Shape pattern using 2d array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

i was trying to solve this pattern but i want using 2D array.

```
for (int row = 1; row<=5; row++) {
    for (int col=1; col<=5; col++) {            
        if ((row == col) || (row == 1 && col == 5) || (row == 2 && col == 4)
            || ( row == 4 && col == 2)  || (row == 5 && col == 1))                   
            System.out.print("*");                 
         else                 
             System.out.print(",_");                                
    }
    System.out.println();       
 }
```

[image: Output i want :]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you feel the need to have an array for this, but here's one possible approach.  The first set of nested loops populates the array and the second set prints it.

```
char[][] xShape = new char[5][5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        xShape[i][j] = ( i == j || i + j == 4 ) ? '*' : '_';
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        System.out.print(xShape[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Feel free to add the commas and square brackets however you see fit.

Comment: sir, i want output exactly like uploaded picture. brackets and comma missing.

Answer (score 0):

***Perfect solution***

```
         char[][] xShape  = new char[5][5];
            for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
                for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
                    xShape[i][j] =  (i==j || i+j==4) ? '*':'_';
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                System.out.print("[");
                for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
                    System.out.print(xShape[i][j]+",");
                }
                System.out.println("]");
            }
```